What is the concept of an accepted default not having a formal name?
Is there a name for the concept of something not having a formal name because it's the default?
I work in software. There is a traditional software architecture that was so normalized, it never had a name -- it was just "the way we did things."
Then a new architecture came along. This new architecture named itself -- something catchy and marketable. And it needed a name because whenever something was talking about it, they needed to differentiate it (the new way) from the default way.
This concept of naming something that is not the default (and the corollary of the default not having a name) -- is there a word for that?

Good question. Only after new flavors come along do brands label the old standy as Original, Classic, or Regular.

What's the opposite of a retronym is related but has no answer; this Q is on retronyms.

I feel like there's a related concept of... "retronym disadvantage." The older thing is considered substandard because it doesn't have a name. The new thing benefits from having a catchy name that sets it apart from the old thing.

The expression 'the good old way' has some currency (albeit in a different domain) and is transparent. But I don't think there's a word for 'a/n article / invention / piece of software / method / process ... in search of a retronym'.

In IT, the old version of the system  is often called "legacy software/architecture"

@Graffito Yeah, and I've always thought this was unfair because of the negative connotation.

"Definition by negation" is part of the conversation here. It suggests Heidegger's hammer. I feel like there's some maxim about some historical figure, along the pattern "Until he showed us X, we had no idea [we were lacking X]," but I can't place it…

There's the idea of an "unmarked category" which I think is at least close to what you're talking about.
